# Is it possible to interpolate table name in insert queries?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using spark sql in databricks.
I would like to parametrize name of the table I am inserting into using the named parameters.
I'm running into issues where spark is giving me UNBOUND_SQL_PARAMETER for **unrelated other parameter**. This seems like spark bug or at least something where error reporting could be improved.

I managed to reproduce the issue locally in spark-shell within docker container

```scala
$ docker pull spark:3.5.1-scala2.12-java17-r-ubuntu
$ docker run --rm -it spark:3.5.1-scala2.12-java17-r-ubuntu /opt/spark/bin/spark-shell
scala> spark.sql("create table person(name string, age int)").show()
scala> spark.sql("describe table person").show()
+--------+---------+-------+
|col_name|data_type|comment|
+--------+---------+-------+
| name   | string  | NULL  |
| age    | int     | NULL  |
+--------+---------+-------+
scala> // Works with hardcoded table name
scala> spark.sql("INSERT INTO person (name,age) VALUES (:name, :age)",Map("name"->"John","age"->50))

scala> spark.sql("SELECT name, age FROM person").show()
+----+---+
|name|age|
+----+---+
|John| 50|
+----+---+

scala> spark.sql("INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER(:mytable) (name,age) VALUES (:name, :age)",Map("mytable"->"person","name"->"John","age"->50))

spark.sql("INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER(:mytable) (name,age) VALUES (:name, :age)",Map("mytable"->"person","name"->"John","age"->50))
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ExtendedAnalysisException: [UNBOUND_SQL_PARAMETER] Found the unbound parameter: name. Please, fix `args` and provide a mapping of the parameter to a SQL literal.; line 1 pos 52;
'InsertIntoStatement HiveTableRelation [`spark_catalog`.`default`.`person`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, Data Cols: [name#44, age#45], Partition Cols: []], [name, age], false, false, false
+- 'UnresolvedInlineTable [col1, col2], [[namedparameter(name), namedparameter(age)]]

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:52)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$6(CheckAnalysis.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$6$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:244)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$5(CheckAnalysis.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$5$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:264)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:533)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$2(CheckAnalysis.scala:264)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.$anonfun$checkAnalysis0$2$adapted(CheckAnalysis.scala:182)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:244)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1(TreeNode.scala:243)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$foreachUp$1$adapted(TreeNode.scala:243)
  at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:943)
  at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:943)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1431)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:243)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis0(CheckAnalysis.scala:182)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis0$(CheckAnalysis.scala:164)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis0(Analyzer.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:160)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis.checkAnalysis$(CheckAnalysis.scala:150)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:188)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:211)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:208)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:219)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:219)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:218)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$4(SparkSession.scala:691)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:682)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:713)
  ... 47 elided
...
```

Question: Is interpolating table names into insert statements like this unsupported? It works fine in other types of queries (SELECT, UPDATE, ...).

Or is it perhaps a bug in query parsing/validation logic? The error complains about unrelated parameter that I definitely am supplying..

Answer (score -1):

Try to use below option :

**Scala code**

val tableName = "mytable"

spark.sql(s"INSERT INTO $tableName .....")

**Python code**

tableName = "mytable"

spark.sql(f"INSERT INTO {tableName} .....")

Comment: That doesn't really solve the prevent sql injection issue, does it?
Moreover I cannot use this workaround in databricks statement execution api, where I don't have access to scala/general programming language features, because I have to submit the query as a string (either with named parameters or with hardcoded table names).